# Create subsets based on a certain sequence of values

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, sequence

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0:20), y = c(50:70),
                 m = c(0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0 ,0 , -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0))
```

I would like to create subsets defined by a sequence of values in column 'm':

A sequence should *start* and *end* with `m == -1`, and there has to be a `1` between the start and finish `-1`. Each subset then includes all rows between the *start* and *end*.

For example, one of the subsets from the data above would look like:

```
Subset1 <- data.frame(x = c(4:10), y = c(54:60), m = c(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1))
#    x  y  m
# 1  4 54 -1 # starts with -1
# 2  5 55  0
# 3  6 56  0
# 4  7 57  1 # contains a 1
# 5  8 58  0
# 6  9 59  0
# 7 10 60 -1 # ends with -1
```

I have been trying a lot and I can't figure out how to do it. I have tried with `mapply` or `for` loops, but always I'm stuck when it comes to set up the pattern, since both ends of the pattern are the same.

For instance, with `mapply`, I've done:

```
List_subsets <- mapply(function(i, j, z) df[i:j:z, , drop = FALSE], -1, 1, -1,
                       SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

But of course, I always get the

```
# error: In i:j:z : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
```

Do you know if that's possible and could you help me out? I would really appreciate your input, since I'm very new to R and it's very challenging for me.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What's your final output format you're seeking

Comment: Preferably a list with the individual subsets so I can iterate a certain function separately in all them.

Comment: Thank you for a nice question. What if you have a sequence in 'm' like `c(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1)`, is it correct to assume that the second -1 is "consumed" by a subset starting with the first -1, so that we only have one group/subset here, i.e. row 1-3? Or could it be two groups, that "share" a `-1`, where row 1-3 is one group, and row 3-5 another? Can you please clarify. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, Please let me know if its your desired outcome:

```
library(stringr)
pattrn <- data.frame(str_locate_all(paste0(df$m+1,collapse=''),'0[1]*?2[1]*?0')[[1]])
## str_locate_all will find all start and end of the pattern -1,1,-1
## to find -1, 1, -1 , I have added 1 to the column, this will remove the negative sign for correct capture of location
## so, the new pattern to be found is 0,2,0, to do this I concatenated the m column and try to find the 0, 2, 0 with regex mentioned
pattrn_rows <- Map(seq, from=pattrn$start, to=pattrn$end)
## converting to data.frame
lapply(pattrn_rows,function(x)df[x,])
## finally subsetting, this step will give the final result into two lists of dataframes
```

**Output:**

```
[[1]]
    x  y  m
5   4 54 -1
6   5 55  0
7   6 56  0
8   7 57  1
9   8 58  0
10  9 59  0
11 10 60 -1

[[2]]
    x  y  m
14 13 63 -1
15 14 64  0
16 15 65  0
17 16 66  1
18 17 67  0
19 18 68  0
20 19 69 -1
```

Comment: Yes, that works very nicely! Thanks a lot for your time and quick response!!!